# difficult with fetching in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am very new in ReactJS , and have some problems with fetching, I hope you can help me.
I write following code:

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-pine-ql0m5)

It's work great, it was fetching "headline" from all data.
But in my localhost when I write same thing, on console it show error like
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjENw.png)

Please help me to resolve that problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please give us a [mcve] of your problem and provide copy pastable code not just a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `useEffect` run on every change, you just need to add empty array for the dependencies. Here is how to fix it

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

You can read more about the `useEffect` hook here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: thank you, it start to work .